# Is it good to run prometheus in the same application server

Tags: amazon-web-services, logging, prometheus, prometheus-operator

I have a VPC, where the backend are in private subnets connected. I am introducing a new logging tool "Prometheus" to it. **`My question is should I spin up an another ec2 on the private subnet where the backend applications are connected or should I run along with the application server machine itself ?`**
If I bring up a new server, I see like if any issue like a disk failure or full happens to the app server then prometheus can help me to say that but if installed in same machine if a sudden disk fails prometheus too will go down, right ?
On second part, which one is more **secure**, I don't know if any port need to be exposed since we run in different servers ? do we need to do that ?

Pls let me know your best experience ?

Comment: Yes, your prometheus monitoring instances should be separate from your actual instance. If you are talking about an env small enough that it's only a couple ec2 instances, I would actually recommend outsourcing monitoring with a service like datadog or new relic.

Comment: but for each metrics I need to expose the ports right ?

Comment: Am still search for a good answer, can anyone explain ?

Comment: "I need to expose the ports right ?" - Yes